# How can we send radar to Venus and reflect it back on earth?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, solar-system

## Question

How is it possible to send laser light to Venus and reflect it back on earth? I believe there is no artificial reflection material e.g. mirror on Venus.

### Background

Veritasium [How One Supernova Measured The Universe](https://youtu.be/ljoeOLuX6Z4?t=433) talks about light travelling slower in the space curved by gravity and the proof by sending laser to Venus.

[image]

## Update

The question title was `How can we send laser light to Venus and reflect it back on earth?` but it was not **laser** but **radar** that Derek mentioned in the Veritasium video.

Comment: Hint: why can you see Venus? Because it is reflecting the light of the Sun!

Comment: @JörgWMittag makes a good point - that mirrors aren't all that reflect - athough in their example what reflects is the atmosphere, whereas this experiment concerns reflection by the surface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The experiment in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_time_delay) reflected radio waves off the surface of Venus, or in some cases Mercury. It was a very large-scale [radar experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar#Reflection). The surface need not be "mirrored" to visible light; any solid is amenable to radar detection, unless [suitably designed not to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_technology#Radar_cross-section_(RCS)_reductions). Neither Mercury nor Venus has a radio-absorbernt or dielectric composite surface that would confound Shapiro's experiment, given the wavelength used.

Comment: In fact, if you go back about a second in the video link, he specifically says Radar.